# how to prove that every cauchy sequence is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces

I just want to know how can I prove that:

Let $\{x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ a real numbers sequence, if $\{x_n\}$ is a cauchy sequence, then $$x_n\longrightarrow x\in\mathbb{R}$$

Comment: But haven't you constructed $\mathbb R$ such that every Cauchy sequence converges ? Else please state from which construction of $\mathbb R$ you want this fact to be proved (dedekind, quasi-endomorphisms) ?

Comment: What properties do you know about the reals. Do you know the least upper bound property?

Comment: Google *ought* to have dozens of references for that result.

Comment: Do you know the Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Basically, there are lots of ways to prove it, and they depend on what knowledge you are starting from...

Comment: Check out this link [Real Number Line is Complete Metric Space](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Number_Line_is_Complete_Metric_Space)

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437904/confused-with-proof-that-all-cauchy-sequences-of-real-numbers-converge) which is actually a duplicate.